# How to solve "current printer is unavailable" message on opening workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel workbook that, on opening, displays a message "Current printer is unavailable. Select another printer." Followed by a dialogue box with a list of print drivers.

Based on [this thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1975828-printer-dialog-box-pops-up-in-excel-file), I thought the problem might be that one of the pages was set to Page Break Preview.  But I've checked all the pages and they're set to Normal view.

What can I do to keep this message from popping up whenever I open the workbook?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that we could take a look at for this one. Here are a few ideas that I have:

**VBA Script or Macro:** It could be that the workbook has an OnOpen script assigned that triggers printing when the workbook is opened. Does the workbook have any macros? Is it .XLSM?

**Print Devices:** Do you see this prompt when opening any other Office documents, including in other Office applications? Are you able to print normally to your default printer? This prompt could mean that Excel is trying to simply query the printers associated with the computer, and one of them isn't responding. It could be a network printer or an old printer that's no longer used but still added to Windows. I'd take a look at which printers are installed and remove any that you no longer use, as well.

Hope this helps! Let me know what you find.

Comment: It is an .XLSM.  I checked for OnOpen scripts, searching the project for the string "Private Sub Workbook"; didn't find any.

Comment: This only happens when I open this particular workbook, or modified versions of it.  Other Office documents open and print fine.

Comment: Just for the sake of troubleshooting, try saving a copy of the affected workbook as XLSX. Then close all Excel windows and open the test version. If the issue doesn't happen with that version, then at least we've narrowed it down to something within the macros/VBA script.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below checklist in order.

1. Save workbooks
2. Restart Printer
3. Restart PC

If the problem persists it may be a [print queue issue](http://www.kuskaya.info/2013/06/09/how-to-troubleshoot-current-printer-is-unavailable-select-another-printer-and-no-default-printer-selected-error-messages/), try deleting the affected print queue.

1. Open Regedit by clicking on **Start** -> **RUN** -> **Regedit**
2. Navigate to the affected print queue, **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** -> **Printers** -> Connections
3. Delete the **,,[YOURPRINTERNAMEHERE]**

[image]

Comment: Work PC so I don't have administrative access :(

Comment: @sigil have you tested another PC? if it's only occurring on your PC maybe your IT department could help.